# How to find and remove the buzzer from a Morphy Richards Breadmaker

Tags: stripboard

I just bought a Morphy Richards breadmaker that is great in all ways, but it beeps in the middle of the night and wakes me up (both when it begins baking and when it's finished). So I was wondering if you could help me locate the buzzer, and then I will try to remove it, or cover it up in some ways.

In advance, thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: I think your on your own with this.

Comment: It’s not in that photo.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a cylindrical black device about 10mm diameter with a small hole at the top. Put a drip of hot glue in the hole or cover it with a bit of Kapton tape and the sound level will greatly decrease.

Here is a photo of a somewhat larger TDK piezo device from another brand (photo from [eBay](https://www.ebay.ca/i/233401585315?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=706-89093-2056-0&mkcid=2&itemid=233401585315&targetid=885401534601&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9000815&poi=&campaignid=9561945108&mkgroupid=98506994779&rlsatarget=pla-885401534601&abcId=1063836&merchantid=10252592&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6t7Sk6nM6AIVDbbICh03dwJwEAQYBiABEgJFvfD_BwE)), but the same applies.

[image]

Comment: And they can usually be muted by application of self-adhesive tape across the hole on top.

Comment: @Transistor  I suggested Kapton adhesive tape because it’s non-flammable. But hot glue is probably inconsistent with that. Cello tape would work as well.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot 

Comment: Just found it and bought a Kapton adhesive tape to try it out. I tried to remove it manually, but that was way too difficult.